# Default RenderTransform Converter syntax

Tags: wpf, xaml, converters, rendertransform

I have a canvas with a RenderTransform applied like so:

```
<Canvas RenderTransform="0.1,0,0,-0.1,0,913">
```

Can anyone tell me what these values mean? I can't seem to find what converter is being used to parse these values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the `RenderTransform` is a [`Transform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transform.aspx) it probably uses the [`TransformConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transformconverter.aspx) which in turn probably creates a [`MatrixTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrixtransform.aspx); from its documentation:

```
<object property="m11, m12, m21, m22, offsetX, offsetY"/>
```

I unnecessarily went ahead and checked the code, the converter calls [`Transform.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transform.parse.aspx):

> Creates a new [Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transform.aspx) from the specified string representation of a transformation matrix.
>
> For more information, see the XAML Attribute Usage section of the [MatrixTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrixtransform.aspx) class page.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, that is what is happening.